# How to refresh a counter on the UI without blocking the rest, in codename one?

Tags: codenameone, event-dispatch-thread

I try to get a score count on the UI, to be refreshed several times per second. The refresh should not prevent the other elements of the UI from working (Buttons should remain clickable etc.)

I read the doc on the `EDT` and tried to add a method called from the constructor of the `Form`:

```
  private void loopScore() {
        Display.getInstance().callSerially(
                () -> {
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            MyApplication.score = MyApplication.score + 1;
                            this.gui_Score.setText(String.valueOf(MyApplication.score));
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            //do something
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

But this does not update `gui_Score` and it blocks the rest of the UI. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to override the `animate` method of the `Form`.

This method is called at each new cycle of the `EDT` (which is every millisecond or so) to verify if there is a need to repaint anything.

Overriding the method allows to insert a line of code updating the text of the `Label` where the score is:

```
@Override
public boolean animate() {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 > lastRenderedTime / 1000) {
        lastRenderedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        computeScore();
        this.gui_Score.setText(String.valueOf(MyApplication.score));
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

private void computeScore() {
    MyApplication.score = MyApplication.score + 3;
}
```

Then, you need to register this animation with the `registerAnimated` method. I do it from the constructor of the `Form`:

```
public Form1(com.codename1.ui.util.Resources resourceObjectInstance) {
    initGuiBuilderComponents(resourceObjectInstance);
    lastRenderedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    registerAnimated(this);
}
```

Now the `Label` with the counter refreshes every second, showing an increment of 3. The rest of the UI remains responsive, nothing is blocking.

(solution found by fiddling with the animation of a clock [demonstrated on this page](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/wiki/Graphics,-Drawing,-Images-&-Fonts))

Comment: You could have also achieved success using a UITimer, or just with java.util.Timer, but with java.util.Timer you would need to have callSerially() inside the TimerTask so that it runs on the EDT.  The reason your original attempt failed was because you used Thread.sleep() on the EDT which will block the entire App pretty much.

Comment: And you can theoretically sleep in invokeAndBlock() although that's not ideal. `TestUtils.waitFor()` does just that...